# Android studio and localizing apps

Tags: android, android-studio, localization, translation

I'm currently working on an app, which will be used (hopefully) by various tourist to my city. as such, i would like to complement as many languages as i can, and i have the appropriate translators to do so. I've read and started to implement the various different resources in the res folder, i already have some translated, i have a folder for each language as described in the guide from google.

How do I make the app initiate as non-English language in my phone while testing? for example Spanish. every time i run it, it's always English, and i would like to see that the app also works in the other languages, but i can't find anywhere how to initiate it.

I realize I might be simply overlooking something basic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of the app is based on the system language. You need to change the language in Settings -> Language & input.

Answer (score 0):

Change phone language from Settings->Language & input

Answer (score 0):

If you use a physico-chimiques devices you have to change the languages of your device

If you use a emulator I think you can set the language on the creation.

If your tester have a android with spanish language,  the app will be automatically on spanish. (if you create a filé string.xml in a values-es folder)